# Input range inside fieldset gets stuck in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html

I have `fieldset` with an `input` of type `range` (from 1 to 10), and a hidden text that is shown when the input value is 5. In Chrome, the slider gets stuck when the mouse passes over the value 5. However, in Firefox this issue does not occur and the input works as expected. I've tried replacing the `fieldset` with a `div` element, which resolves the issue in Chrome, but I'd prefer to keep the `fieldset` element for accessibility purposes. Is there any other approach to make this particular `fieldset` work in Chrome the same way it does in Firefox?

```html
<fieldset>
  <input type="range" id="inputRange" min=1 max=10 value=1>
  <p id="text" hidden>Hey!</p>
</fieldset>

<script>
  const range = document.getElementById('inputRange');
  const text = document.getElementById('text');
  range.addEventListener('input', () => text.hidden = range.value != 5);
</script>
```

Comment: If you remove the hidden state from the `<p>` tag and use `range.addEventListener('input', () => text.innerText = range.value != 5 ? "" : "Hey!"` it seems to work fine on chrome. -- It looks like a bug with hidden elements inside a fieldset. Chrome somehow looses the dragged element when an element inside a fieldset applies or looses a hidden state. - And it works fine if you just use the keyboard. It doesn't get stuck.

Comment: Thanks @Christopher for raising the ticket!  That's actually the root cause of the issue, confirmed by someone from the Chromium project already.

Comment: Just for the record, there is a typo on the link you provided. This is the right one: [Issue 1404774](https://crbug.com/1404774).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real solution will come from [Issue 1404774](https://crbug.com/1404774). Meanwhile, as a workaround, we listen to the `change` event to unhide the text, which unlike `input`, does not have any conflicts with `fieldset` and hidden elements.

As an additional "feature", we also use the `input` event but only to show/update the current value.

Finally, and just for the record, `input` is triggered every time the slider is dragged, and `change` is triggered just once, when the mouse button is released after dragging the slider.

```js
currentValue.innerText = inputRange.value;
inputRange.addEventListener('change', () => text.innerText = inputRange.value != 5 ? "" : "Hey!");
inputRange.addEventListener('input', () => currentValue.innerText = inputRange.value);
```

```css
#text:empty {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <input type="range" id="inputRange" min=1 max=10 value=1>
  <p id="text"></p>
  <p id="currentValue"></p>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my comment, it works fine if you edit the content of the p-element and don't change the visibility state.

Also to make it look similar to a completly hidden p-element, remove the margin from it, while it is empty.

```js
inputRange.addEventListener('input', () => text.innerText = inputRange.value != 5 ? "" : "Hey!");
```

```css
#text:empty {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <input type="range" id="inputRange" min=1 max=10 value=1>
  <p id="text"></p>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: This is a valid workaround, and it will surely play well on many cases. However, in the project I'm working on, we're relying on the `hidden` attribute and I cannot easily get rid of it to apply your suggestion. I'm still looking for another approach.